# Looping around elements of a message and include root node

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, biztalk, biztalk-2013

The first suggestion in this article - http://blog.eliasen.dk/2006/11/05/LoopingAroundElementsOfAMessage.aspx shows how to loop through an XML and and split the XML into individual elements in an orchestration.

What if I want to include the root node of the original xml in all the subsequent individual xmls? For instance, this is the xml they have:

```
<Employees>
<Employee title="mgr">
</Employee>
<Employee title="vp">
</Employee>
<Employee title="ceo">
</Employee>
</Employees>
```

what will the expression look like if I want every element output, to be enclosed in `<Employees>` element:

```
<Employees>
<Employee title="mgr">
</Employee>
</Employees>

<Employees>
<Employee title="vp">
</Employee>
</Employees>

<Employees>
<Employee title="ceo">
</Employee>
</Employees>
```

The expression used in that example is this:

```
EmployeeMessage = xpath(InputMessage, "/*[local-name()='Employees' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='Employee' and namespace-uri()=''][" + counterStr + "]");
```

I'm sending this xml to a message queue system that expects the root node to be like this.

Please help. Thank you.

**Update:**

I found out that the root node needs to include a namespace definition for this to work. Like this:

`<Employees xmlns="http://mycompany.com/hr.xsd">
    <Employee title="mgr">
    </Employee>
    </Employees>`

How do we include the namespace definition for the root node in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
varXmlDoc.LoadXml("<Employees xmlns='http://mycompany.com/hr.xsd'/>");
EmployeeMessage = varXmlDoc;
xpath(EmployeeMessage, "/Employees") = xpath(InputMessage, "/*[local-name()='Employees' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='Employee' and namespace-uri()=''][" + counterStr + "]");
```

where 'varXmlDoc' is type System.Xml.XmlDocument

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked, but there was a requirement I forgot; the namespace definition should be included in the root node in the output. Please see my Update. How can we achieve that with LoadXml () ?

Comment: Thanks @Bert  Is what I'm trying to do here called debatching?

Comment: I suppose it's a form of debatching. Normally you have an envelope with the batched messages inside and you would remove the envelope when you debatch the message. This is how envelope schemas work in the XML disassembler. If there are values in the envelope you want to retain with the debatched messages the disassembler can write those values to context properties. In your example you are debatching but then adding the envelope back on.

That's probably not very clear. This is an example of what I'm talking about: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa546772.aspx